# tjDecompress2 takes more time to execute if called after a delay

Tags: c, jpeg, mjpeg, libjpeg, libjpeg-turbo

The following code is  written to test the perfomance of libjpeg-turbo on my system

```
unsigned char *source; 
unsigned int _jpegSize = 0; 
unsigned long long GetTime( void )
{
    struct timeval tv;
    struct timezone tz;

    gettimeofday(&tv, &tz);

    return tv.tv_sec * 1000000ULL + tv.tv_usec;
}
int main(int argc,char**argv)
{
    if(argc < 3)
        return 0;
    char *fileName = argv[1];
    int fileSize = atoi(argv[2]);

    source = (unsigned char*)malloc(fileSize);
    ReadFile(argv[1],fileSize); //Reads the file and copy the data to source buffer

for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
{

    unsigned char* _compressedImage = source;   
    int jpegSubsamp, width, height;
    tjhandle _jpegDecompressor = tjInitDecompress();
    tjDecompressHeader2(_jpegDecompressor, _compressedImage, fileSize, &width, &height, &jpegSubsamp);
    unsigned char dstBuffer[width*height*3]; //!< will contain the decompressed image

    unsigned long long t1 = GetTime();

    tjDecompress2(_jpegDecompressor, _compressedImage, fileSize, dstBuffer, width, 0/*pitch*/, height, TJPF_RGB, TJFLAG_FASTDCT);

    unsigned long long t2 = GetTime();
    printf("TimeTaken: %llu microseconds for %f ms\n", t2-t1,(float)((t2-t1)/(1000))); 

    tjDestroy(_jpegDecompressor);    
    usleep(50000);   
}
```

it decodes  a jpeg image repeatedly in a for loop.  On my system **tjDecompress2** takes around **5-7ms** to decode a 1024x768 image. The issue is that if I add a  **usleep(50000)**  command at the end of the loop the execution time for **tjDecompress2** increases to **25-28ms**. What is the reason for this behaviour and how it can be fixed. 
 Basically I want to read MJPEG  images fro m a USB camera at 20 FPS and decode them using libjpeg-turbo so the purpose of adding **usleep(5000)** is to simulate the time between the arrival of two successive frames

Comment: Most likely reason is *cache effects*. If you look at the very first iteration of the loop, you'll see that it too takes longer than the others; this is because the data and the structures used by the decompressor are not cached. If the system has sufficient amount of work so that the delay is long enough for other work the core is doing to evict the old data from cache, it would explain the timing differences. Thing is, *the longer timing* is more likely to be correct, because the data for successive images will not be cached anyway.

Comment: In your case, this is not a big problem at all. You can use one thread to keep reading the USB data into a triple buffer (so that one image can be processed, while another is waiting to be processed, and a third one is being received from USB), so that you *process at the same time you receive data*. This means that to reach 20 FPS, you have (almost) 1000 ms / 20 = 50 ms to decode each frame. If you save the separate frames, use a second worker thread (and another double or triple buffer) to save the frames.

Comment: what should I do if a need to increase the FPS arises moreover I cant keep the cpu busy because i need to process the decoded frames for my application.

Comment: You can use several decoder threads in parallel, if the decoder library is thread-safe. Most computers nowadays have several cores, so just because it takes *one* core to decode a frame 25-30 ms does not mean the computer is limited to 33 frames per second. In general, the known working approach is to ensure that all cores have work to do, even when you are waiting for data to be transmitted.